# pre-populate form with masked URL

Tags: php, javascript, forms, url

Is there a way to pre-populate form with masked URL using PHP or javascript?

in the index.php,  I have used the base64_encode function to masked firstname=peter&lastname=pan to a variable and echo out this

example.php?randomstring

then on the example.php form file, I used base64_decode to decode the randomstring
but I only get firstname=peter&lastname=pan, and not able to use it as $_GET[firstname] and $_GET[lastname] variables.
so is there a way to use the randomstring variables to pre-populate it on the form?

or any other easy way to pre-populate form with masked URL?

Thanks,

Pat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it please:

```
$query = "firstname=peter&lastname=pan";
$encodedQuery = base64_encode($query);

parse_str(base64_decode($encodedQuery), $result);

$_GET = array_merge($_GET, $result);
print_r($_GET);
```

Then you can populate as usual.